# Is it “what movie did you watch?” Or “ which movie did you watch?”

Tags: north-american-english

I’m confused about the right way of saying it. Please tell me the correct answer and why it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What movie is for when you dont know the selection of movies.

Which movie implies there was some sort of list, and they chose that one from there.

In most cases "What" would suffice, unless for example, you watched a movie at the same time too and you just saw your friend coming out of the cinema